# Pushing all the values of an input class into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on what I learned and what I read here on Stack as well, I wrote a code that should get all the values of a specified class of input and pushing them into an array.

What I think this jQuery sript should do is:

- create an empty array called `myArray`
- when `#subButton` is clicked an iteration on the `<input class=".req"` starts, pushing the **value** of each `<input class=".req"` into `myArray`

The problem is that anything is displayed in the console, as nothing happened, so I guess there's a conceptual/writing error.

**jQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var myArray = [];
    $('#subButton').on('click', function() {
        $('.req').each(function() {
            myArray.push($(this).val()); 
            console.log(myArray);
        });
    });     

});
```

**HTML :**

```
<form id="iForm">
  <input type="text" id="i1" class=".req" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" id="i2" placeholder="Surname">
  <input type="text" id="i3" placeholder="Text A">
  <input type="text" id="i4" class=".req" placeholder="Text B">

  <input type="button" id="subButton" value="Registrati">
</form>
```

Comment: you have ".req" as your className. it should be "req"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having fixed your `class` attributes to remove the leading period character, you can use:

```
var myArray = $('.req').get().map(function(el) { return el.value });
```

Where `$(...).get()` converts the jQuery collection into a standard array, and `.map` extracts the field values.

This is somewhat cleaner than using `.each` with a `push`.

Comment: You solved me the next problem that was the duplication of the values every time the button was clicked: you're a soothsayer Alnitak! Thanks

Comment: @brigo right, because the `.map` always creates the array from scratch

Answer (score 3):

You've to remove the `.` before the classes in your HTML inputs :

```
<input type="text" id="i1" class=".req" placeholder="Name">
__________________________________^
<input type="text" id="i4" class=".req" placeholder="Text B">
__________________________________^
```

Should be :

```
<input type="text" id="i1" class="req" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" id="i4" class="req" placeholder="Text B">
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var myArray = [];
  $('#subButton').on('click', function() {
    $('.req').each(function() {
      myArray.push($(this).val()); 
      console.log(myArray);
    });
  });     

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="iForm">
  <input type="text" id="i1" class="req" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" id="i2" placeholder="Surname">
  <input type="text" id="i3" placeholder="Text A">
  <input type="text" id="i4" class="req" placeholder="Text B">

  <input type="button" id="subButton" value="Registrati">
</form>
```

Comment: Shame on me! I wrote ten times the script thinking the error was there due to my inexperience on Javascript/jQuery, and then the problem was the dot. Thanks Zakaria!